# Reading data from embedded controller using COM port

Tags: java, com-port

we are receiving data from controller using terminal software and as well as also java program ..
but think is that we get proper data on terminal software but java program can not show like terminal .. actually data come in ASCII and we convert to HEX terminal application show proper data but java program can not show [terminal data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWj3C.png).....
[java program data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJitx.png)

```java
import java.io.*; // IOException
import java.util.*; // Scanner
import jssc.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Emiliarge
 */
public class ComPortSendReceive1 {

    private static SerialPort serialPort;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

        if (portNames.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no serial-ports :( You can use an emulator, such ad VSPE, to create a virtual serial port.");
            System.out.println("Press Enter to exit...");
            try {
                System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }

        // Ð²Ñ‹Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚Ð°
        System.out.println("Available com-ports:");
        for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Type port name, which you want to use, and press Enter...");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String portName = in.next();

        // writing to port
        serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
        try {
            // opening port
            serialPort.openPort();

            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                                 SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                 SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                 SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
                                          SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);

            serialPort.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
            // writing string to port
            serialPort.writeString("Hurrah!!!");

            System.out.println("String wrote to port, waiting for response..");
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in writing data to port: " + ex);
        }
    }

    // receiving response from port
    private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
                try {
                    // Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð²ÐµÑ‚Ð° Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚Ð°
                    String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());


                    for (char ch : receivedData.toCharArray()) {
                            System.out.format("%H ", ch);



                        } // prints "31 32 2E 30 31 33 "



                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: both pictures are identical

Comment: data mismatch in between java program and terminal ... in ASCII to HEX conversion

Comment: Terminal data is --- D2 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 CC 0F 24 28 07 0D 3C 7C 05 23 00 0A 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3C DD 19 19 19 19 19 00 00 1C 00 1D 19 19 18 1A 00 62 10 00 00 00 7A CC                              and java Program data is ----- FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 42 FFFD F 24 28 7 D 3C 7C 5 23 0 A 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3C FFFD 1A 19 1A 1A 1A 0 0 A 0 A 19 1A 19 1E 0 62 10 0 0 0 5F FFFD

Comment: First D2 show in java FFFD and CC is also shows FFFD